# Missing UE4Game binary. You may have to build the UE4 project with your IDE. Alternatively,Use CommandLine

Tags: windows, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to start a simple built in Unreal engine game and build it on windows. I have tried multiple times and in multiple platforms and everytime unreal engine fails to build an executable. What am I missing?
Current setting is clean puzzle game example with starter content. Same happens with empty project with full new build enable. All other platforms and plugins are disable and only windows is selected on `supported platform` setting and shipping is selected as build config on packaging. But still it cant build on windows 32bit or 64 bit. It shows the message of this post title.

> How to build an executable from Unreal engine after having this message?

Here is last few lines from log output from build :

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: DDC Resource Stats
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: =======================================================================================================
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: Asset Type                          Total Time (Sec)  GameThread Time (Sec)  Assets Built  MB Processed
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: ----------------------------------  ----------------  ---------------------  ------------  ------------
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: MaterialShader                                  1.07                   1.07             0          6.12
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: Texture (Streaming)                             0.57                   0.00             0         16.29
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: PhysX (BodySetup)                               0.12                   0.12             0          1.30
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: GlobalShader                                    0.09                   0.09             0          4.47
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: Texture (Inline)                                0.07                   0.07             0         33.64
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: StaticMesh                                      0.03                   0.03             0          3.52
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: NavCollision                                    0.00                   0.00             0          0.03
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: DistanceField                                   0.00                   0.00             0          0.00
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogCookCommandlet: Display: SoundWave                                       0.00                   0.00             0          0.03
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogInit: Display:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogInit: Display: Success - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   LogInit: Display:
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):   Execution of commandlet took:  6.05 seconds
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): Took 12.9337712s to run UE4Editor-Cmd.exe, ExitCode=0
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): ********** COOK COMMAND COMPLETED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): ********** STAGE COMMAND STARTED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): ERROR: Stage Failed. Missing receipt 'D:\UE\MyProject4forBuilds\Binaries\Win32\MyProject4forBuilds.target'. Check that this target has been built.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)):        (see C:\Users\Rifat\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\G+Epic+Games+UE_4.21\Log.txt for full exception trace)
PackagingResults: Error: Stage Failed. Missing receipt 'D:\UE\MyProject4forBuilds\Binaries\Win32\MyProject4forBuilds.target'. Check that this target has been built.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=103 (Error_MissingExecutable)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (32-bit)): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Missing UE4Game binary.You may have to build the UE4 project with your IDE. Alternatively, build using UnrealBuildTool with the commandline:UE4Game <Platform> <Configuration>
LogRendererCore: Warning: FlushRenderingCommands called recursively! 2 calls on the stack.
LogRendererCore: Warning: FlushRenderingCommands called recursively! 2 calls on the stack.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
PackagingResults: Error: Stage Failed.... MyProject4forBuilds.target'. Check that this target has been built.
```

The target file is a Package for the platform you are building and launching for - in your logs that's Win32, you probably want Win64. You must first create this Package. (I had difficulty figuring this out too and just solved it for myself).

1. Install [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). VS 2019 is suitable for UE4.24 and provides C compilation tools that UE4 can depend on (that's Visual Studio, **not** VS Code)
2. From the UE4 application menu, select File -> Package Project -> Windows -> Windows (64-bit). A folder selection will appear, the folder of your project is fine to start with. This creates a Package your build & launch process can target.

You should see a set of logs begin creating your Project target, starting with text like this:

```
LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   3.67ms
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Running AutomationTool...
...and a lot more
```

Assuming that goes well and you see `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, you should now be able to Launch your level. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I can not retest it right now, but when I tested before, I tested with both 32 and 64 bit versions, I have VS 2017+2019. I also tested for android. UE can open files on VS too. But the project was not building showing the title error, leading to this question.

Comment: Are you certain you performed **Step 2**, to build the Package binary for Win32 or Win64? This creates the missing file that the Build and Launch stage depends on and is complaining about not being able to find.You only need to do this step once, and then you should be able to Build and Launch many times over - for whichever platforms a Package binary target has been created for.

Comment: Yes, sure. And tested right now failed again. I have added the UE on a different folder. I think reinstalling everything will work.

Comment: The path that you choose is critical, your Build process is expecting you to have chosen `D:\UE\MyProject4forBuilds` when creating the Package. The Package binary then gets put into `D:\UE\MyProject4forBuilds\Binaries\{platform}`. It's worth taking a look in that folder, for example my `Binaries\Win64` dir has files in it, in particular `myproject.target`, which Step 2 created.

If you've done that, are you sure you're getting the exact same error? `Stage Failed. Missing receipt`, same path, correct build platform?

And if you are, sorry this didn't solve your problem :( Best of luck.